# XmlPullParser setInput issue

Tags: android

I have problem with setInput() method. When I've provided plain StringReader and parse XML

```
locationsXml.setInput(new StringReader("<locations>" + "<location>" etc.[...]
```

Everything gone well, but if I want to load file from resources:

```
locationsXml.setInput(new FileReader("res/xml/locations.xml"));
```

File is not being loaded.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have create a Inputstream from the file in your resources (provided the resource xml is placed in 'assets' folder). You can get control of that resource using :

context.getAssets.open(name of the file);

eg - InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(locations.xml);

Noww - you can use this inputStream to do anything you want.

Or

Put the xml into /res/raw folder. It looks like openRawResource opens resources from that folder only. You can also try getResources().getXml(com.MYCLass.R.xml.programs); which will return you instance of XML parser.

InputStream object = this.getResources()
                     .openRawResource(R.raw.fileName);